# varargin and narginchk in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have come across PART of a code in MATLAB in a toolbox that I don't understand

```
elseif (txMode==2) 

narginchk(7, 7);
numTx = varargin{1};
numRx = varargin{2};

switch numTx
    case 2    
        numCSRRE_RB = 4*2*2; 
    case 4      
        numCSRRE_RB = 4*3*2; 
end
```

I don't understand what `narginchk` and `varargin` are used for in this example, and why is that the output of `varargin{1}` would be either 2 or 4 (a conclusion I came up with when looking at the code after `switch`).

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**varargin** is a matlab syntax that allows a matlab function to receive any number of arguments. Since it is a cell, you access its content using *{}* as you can see in your code snippet:

```
numTx = varargin{1};
numRx = varargin{2};
```

You can read more about *nargin* [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html).

**narginchk** is a variable that checks the number of arguments provided to the function. In your case:

```
narginchk(7, 7);
```

If the input is lower than 7 (the first one) or greater than 7 (the second one) it throws an error. Therefore your function needs to receive exactly 7 arguments to work.

You can read more about *narginchk* [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/narginchk.html)